# ERROR 'pip install mysqlclient' on Ubuntu 18.04 and python3.8

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu-18.04

i have installed `sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev` but still error like this..

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/9b/5db9a03e2088a87c26e3e4d4c7f7e8f4c2dbae610f9521cdfac15755a795/mysqlclient-1.4.5.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ridho619/Desktop/Dev/Env/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-apajn0g3/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-apajn0g3/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-apajn0g3/mysqlclient/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-apajn0g3/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/ridho619/Desktop/Dev/Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
      File "/home/ridho619/Desktop/Dev/Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/home/ridho619/Desktop/Dev/Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install libffi-dev` as well? This post indicates it might be the problem: https://bugs.python.org/issue31652

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.5-minimal
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 and found this solution to be useful for python version 3.7.5

Step 1. Install 'libpython3.7-dev' via terminal

```
> sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-dev
```

Step 2: Install latest version of 'mysqlclient' using pip, in my case 1.4.6

```
> python3 -m pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6
```